# Reference Request: Greatest Even (Odd) Integer function

Tags: reference-request

This probably isn't the most important question, but I'm working on something where I've found it convenient to define the following two functions (on the integers):
$$
I_o(q):=
\begin{cases}
  q & q \text{ is odd } \\
  q-1 & q \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{ and }
\qquad
I_e(q):=
\begin{cases}
  q & q \text{ is even } \\
  q-1 & q \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}.
$$

So $I_o(q)$ is just the largest odd number less than or equal to $q$ and $I_e(q)$ is the same, except for even numbers. I feel that I've seen this function before with a notation similar as to that of floor, but I've had little luck googling it. So I was curious if there was a common notation for this function.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$I_o(q) = 2 \left\lfloor \frac{q-1}{2} \right\rfloor + 1 = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lc}
q & q \text{ is odd} \\
q-1 & q \text{ is even} 
\end{array}
\right.$$

Similarly,

$$
I_e(q) = 2 \left\lfloor \frac{q}{2} \right\rfloor.
$$

Comment: This gives a formula for the functions, but OP was asking for a common notation (if there is one).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'd call this common notation, but Microsoft Office seems to have a function EVEN(x) that rounds $x$ up to the nearest even integer. Of course, Microsoft has a strange definition of "up", as EVEN(-1) is -2, not 0. See [this MS Office link.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/even-function-HA001160989.aspx)